# How to handle data from sqlite query?

Tags: c#, ado.net

I have a sqlite-query that gets the following data:

```
    private GetAllPlayerAttributesFromDB()
{
    IDbCommand dbcmd = dbconn.CreateCommand();

    string sqlQueryPlayer = "SELECT player_id, ability_id, value FROM playerabilities";
    dbcmd.CommandText = sqlQueryPlayer;
    IDataReader reader = dbcmd.ExecuteReader();

    IDictionary<int, int> dict = new Dictionary<int, int>();

    while (reader.Read())
    {
      int player_id = reader.GetInt32(0);
      int ability_id = reader.GetInt32(1);
      int value= reader.GetInt32(2);

       // I have no idea how to save the data now
       dict.Add(ability_id, value);
    }

    reader.Close();
    reader = null;
    dbcmd.Dispose();
    dbcmd = null;
}



╔════════════╦════════════╦═══════╗
║ player_id  ║ ability_id ║ value ║
╠════════════╬════════════╬═══════╣
║ "16"       ║ "0"        ║ "56"  ║
║ "16"       ║ "1"        ║ "52"  ║
║ "16"       ║ "2"        ║ "62"  ║
║ "16"       ║ "3"        ║ "72"  ║
║ "16"       ║ "4"        ║ "64"  ║
║ "28"       ║ "0"        ║ "41"  ║
║ "28"       ║ "1"        ║ "49"  ║
║ "28"       ║ "2"        ║ "55"  ║
║ "28"       ║ "3"        ║ "60"  ║
║ "28"       ║ "4"        ║ "65"  ║
║ "41"       ║ "0"        ║ "72"  ║
║ "41"       ║ "1"        ║ "71"  ║
║ "41"       ║ "2"        ║ "79"  ║
║ "41"       ║ "3"        ║ "84"  ║
║ "41"       ║ "4"        ║ "52"  ║
╚════════════╩════════════╩═══════╝
```

**How I want the use the data:**
I want to get all abilities and values from one player by using his player_id as key. For example if I need the data from player 16, then I want to get (0, 56), (1,52), (2, 62)... or an array with int[] values = [56, 52, 62, 72, 64] for each player.

Now I want to save this data in a performant way. In PHP I would use an associative array. How could I do this in C#? (I have read some examples about dictionaries, but I am not able to use them for my problem. Maybe dictionaries are the wrong approach for this?)

Comment: So do you mean you have the SQL statement and you need to know how to execute it? There are many choices for what format to get the data in. A common way is to use Entity Framework to obtain a `List<T>` of a custom type containing the properties matching the columns. Show what you have done so far.

Comment: @Crowcoder pls look at my edits ;)

Comment: `reader["player_id"]` will get you the value of the first field in that row, for instance. Lots of examples of using ADO.NET readers online if you search. You can then put that into whatever data structure you choose. Dictionaries are a reasonable choice and there should be no reason you can't use one here. If you've tried and had a problem, show us what you tried, then we can fix it.

Comment: Why can't you use a dictionary? Also you should use a `using` statement instead of manually calling `Close` and `Dispose`.

Comment: @ADyson yeah that is not my problem. My problem is that I don't know how to save these values in a dictionary. In PHP I would use something like this: $arPA[$db["player_id"]][$db["ability_id"]]["value"] = $db["value"];

Comment: have you googled how to create a dictionary? "Cannot" is not a problem statement or error message, it simply indicates a lack of research. _Unless_ you tried to do it and failed somehow. If so, show us, and explain what went wrong.

Comment: @ADyson Pls look at my edits.  I know how to use a single dictionary, but I have a problem with my encapsulated data type.

Comment: the sensible thing would be to have a "Player" object of which the "abilities" dictionary is a property. the Player ID would be a property of the Player object also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to define a data structure to hold your data.

A simple one would be a class that represents one line

```
public class Player
{
   public int Id {get; set;}
   public int Ability {get;set;}
   public int Value {get;set;}
}
```

And add each row to a `List<Player>`.
However, then you would have 5 rows for each player.

Another option is a class for just Ability/Value

```
public class AbilityValue
{
   public int Ability {get;set;}
   public int Value {get;set;}
}
```

and store that in a `Dictionary<int, List<AbilityValue>>`. This needs some explaining:

- The key is the player_id
- The value is a list of ability/value pairs that you read

The way to use this:

- read a row from the data
- see if you already have that key in your dictionary
- if so, add the new ability/value to that list
- if not, add a new item with the player_id as key. Don't forget to initialize that list

If you know that "Ability" is always between 0 and 4, you could also use an array of size 5 as value of your dictionary. Then you use the ability as index into that array, to set the value.

Comment: Thank you, this makes it very clear ;)

Your last paragraph (the way to use this) was the key for my understanding problem !

Answer (score 2):

Probably the easiest thing for the code you already have is to populate a `DataTable` which is an in-memory "table". It has rows and columns.

```
IDataReader reader = dbcmd.ExecuteReader();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Load(reader);
```

> Update

Once you have a data table loaded you can convert the data to instances of Players (for instance).

Given these classes:

```
class PlayerDetails
{
    public string AbilityID { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

class Player
{
    public string PlayerID { get; set; }
    public List<PlayerDetails> Details { get; set; }
}
```

You can obtain a `List<Player>` each with a `Details` property containing a `List<PlayerDetails>`:

```
var groupedByPlayer = dt.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(d => d["player_id"]).Select(b => new
    Player
{
    PlayerID = b.Key.ToString(),
    Details = b.Select(bp => new PlayerDetails
    {
        AbilityID = bp[1].ToString(),
        Value = bp[2].ToString()
    }).ToList()
});
```

That probably looks pretty ugly if you're not familiar with Linq but if you understand SQL GROUP BY it is similar except you end up with instances of your `Player` class.